# class won't recognize user input?

Tags: java, arrays, class, input, user-input

The program will not recognize that I have entered a value for gerbil.foodTypes (giving me a value of 0 for gerbil.foodName.length. Why?

```
class Gerbil {
public int foodTypes;
public String[] foodName = new String[foodTypes];
}
public class mainmethod {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Gerbil gerbil = new Gerbil();
    System.out.println("How many types of food do the gerbils eat?");
    gerbil.foodTypes = keyboard.nextInt();
    for (int x = 0; x < gerbil.foodTypes ; x++) { 
        System.out.println("Enter the name of food item " + (x+1));
        gerbil.foodName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Maximum consumed per gerbil:");
        gerbil.foodMax[x] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int foodTypes;
public String[] foodName = new String[foodTypes];
```

`foodTypes` is 0 when `new String[foodTypes]` is evaluated so `foodName` is always a zero length array.

Maybe add a constructor that takes `foodTypes`.

```
Gerbil gerbil = new Gerbil(keyboard.nextInt());
```

Comment: What's a constructor do?

Comment: I tried what you put, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct your class, your array 'foodName' is initiated with a length of zero. The reason for this is that when you declare an integer eg.`public int foodTypes'`, all the compiler sees is `public int foodTypes = 0;`

Arrays cannot be resized after you have initialized them so you cannot 'reset' the size of the array.

I would add a constructor that takes a number from input and assigns that to foodTypes so it is not 0.

here is some untested code:

```
class Gerbil {
public int foodTypes;
public String[] foodName;

public Gerbil(int num){
    this.foodTypes = num;
    this.foodName = new String[foodTypes];
}
}
public class Assignment4 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many types of food do the gerbils eat?");
        Gerbil gerbil = new Gerbil(keyboard.nextInt());
    for (int x = 0; x < gerbil.foodTypes ; x++) { 
        System.out.println("Enter the name of food item " + (x+1));
        gerbil.foodName[x] = keyboard.nextLine();
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Maximum consumed per gerbil:");
        gerbil.foodMax[x] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is some further documentation on arrays.